# Parse Partial Protobuf Buffer

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm developing a client and server app that shares messages between them using Protobuf. 
The messages could be long sized so I split it and send it to the server with a header attached.
The header contains the length of the data, its type etc.

I used SerializedAsString to serialized the message to send it over a named pipe. In the server side, I get the message and parse it as a string. 
However, I'm getting an error - probably because the protobuf message is not a complete message (I read only the 4 bytes header).

I'm avoiding sending the header alone because I will need to attach it to the buffer after that and it might be error-prone because it's not atomic.

Do there are any official solutions for that? How it usually done using protobuf?

Comment: The [Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) support fragmentation and reassembly of packets. And if you're using UDP it's packet-based which means you will receive a full packet (or you won't receive it at all) even if it's large. Only with TCP, which is streaming and without boundaries, you need to add something like a header with the packet length. Once you've done that there's no need for your own fragmentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, I lied. it's not a socket. It's a named pipe. So the data is transfered raw.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Then please edit your question to include that small (but important) detail. :)